# Function to fetch all emails from mongodb database of all the users using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database `email-service` which has a collection `users` and each member of the collection has `email` and `password` field. I want to fetch all the emails in the collection.

I have already connected to the proper collection in a proper database. Every other operation like `insert()`, `find_one()`, `initialize()` is working properly but `find()` operation is returning a cursor which is fine but when I iterate over it, doesn't print anything

```
Database.initialize()
user_emails = Database.find(collection="users", query={"email": {}})
for user in user_emails:
    print(user)
```

I want a `dict` or a `list` of all the `emails` in the collection `users`

Comment: Have you tried something like -  `user_emails = dict(Database.users.find())` then `print('email is {user_emails['email']}')` and `print(user_emails.items())` for investigation

Comment: Meant `for key, value in user_emails.items(): print(key, value)` for verifying

Comment: I tried your given syntax it shows that "'Cursor' object has no attribute 'items'" @DaveStSomeWhere

Comment: Yes, my mistake - please try this instead - `user_emails = list(Database.users.find())` then `for doc in user_emails: print(doc.items())`

Comment: I guess `Database` is a `class` in your python code. Can you show your `find()` method of your class?